# Extract substring containing multiple double quote marks JAVA

Tags: java, regex

i want to extract all values between double quote marks in JAVA

sample string:

```
i am a sample string. "name":"Alfred","age":"95","boss":"Batman" end of sample
```

the end result should be an array of: [name,Alfred,age,95,boss,Batman]

*actual string will contain unknown number of values between ""

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried so far and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: to be honest i have nothing. i thought about searching for indexOf ":" and then retrieve values from both ends. but im sure theres a better way

Comment: @zvikachu use this `"\"([^\"]*)\""` regex and get the string you want from group index 1.

Comment: I don't know if you are trying to parse JSON or not, but if you does, better off grab a library somewhere rather than writing regex without the specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare an array and then store the match results to that. `([^\"]*)` captures any  character but not of `"` zero or more times. `()` called capturing group which is used to capture the characters which are matched by the pattern present inside that group. Later we could refer those captured characters through back-referencing.

```
String s = "i am a sample string. \"name\":\"Alfred\",\"age\":\"95\",\"boss\":\"Batman\" end of sample";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"");
ArrayList<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
while(matcher.find()){
        allMatches.add(matcher.group(1));
 }
System.out.println(allMatches);
```

Output:

```
[name, Alfred, age, 95, boss, Batman]
```